# Jquery add + or minus to class selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

I'm using

```
<script>
$("#a-slots-16-history div:nth-child(odd)").addClass(function() {
    return "slick-toggle" + $(this).index();
});
</script>
```

to give a value to every other div on on my website so the 3rd div will have the class .slick-toggle-2 (as 0 is a value)

however i want to manipulate this to take the numeric value of the previous div so -1 from the value so in fact the 3rd div would have the class .slick-toggle-1

Comment: Not really sure what you want to achieve...`$(this).index() - 1` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly.. why not just subtract 1 from the integer returned by $(this).index()?

```
<script>
    $("#a-slots-16-history div:nth-child(odd)").addClass(function() {
        return "slick-toggle" + ($(this).index() - 1);
    });
</script>
```